# How to add specific sound on dragged image

Tags: javascript, html

The idea is like this:

You hear a sound then you have to drag and drop the right image into the box. I want to use this to teach my daughter about animals, and for myself, I want to learn more about these features.

I really hope someone can help me out. Much thanks for your time.

Here is the code:

```
<html>   
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #div1 {width:200px;height:158px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
        function drag(ev)
        {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Jamila sleep het juiste diertje naar de vierkant</p>
    <audio????
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    <img id="drag1" src="eend.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="200" height="158">
<img id="drag2" src="tigr.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="200" height="158">
```

Yours sincerly,

Orhan

Comment: Here's a tutorial about audio API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video There's also a tutorial about drag'n'drop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations but I can see that you've done that part well.

Comment: what I want to realise is that after hearing a animal sound the right image have to be placed into the border..